# Undefined variable: data in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

Undefined variable: data error occure when i want to display data from database.
Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{

    $data = Trial::where('zipcode',$request->zipcode)->select('lat','lng')->first();
    $lat = $data->lat;
    $lng = $data->lng;
    $distance = 5 ;// Diatanse in kms
    $query = Trial::getByDistance($lat, $lng, $distance);

    $ids = [];
    //Extract the id's
    if(!empty($query)) {
        foreach($query as $q)
        {
            array_push($ids, $q->id);
        }
    }

    // Now write final query 
    if(!empty($ids)){
        $results = DB::table('trial')->whereIn( 'id', $ids)->where('zipcode');
    }

    return view('search.searchhome',compact('data',$data));
    dd($data);

}
```

**Blade**

```
<p>
@foreach($data as $dat)
    {{$dat->zipcode}}
@endforeach                           
</p>
```

Comment: If you want to use `data` I'm unsure why you're using `compact`.

Comment: There's also a question of you treating $data as though it's an array of row objects, but from your controller code, it looks like it's the object of the first row only?

Comment: `$results = DB::table('trial')->whereIn( 'id', $ids)->where('zipcode');` you should use `get()` or `first()` to fetch data

Comment: That's a good point. Did you mean to pass the `$results` variable (noting @quickSwap's comment) to the view, rather than `$data`?

Comment: Not Working sir.

Comment: what you need to pass exactly? and what's being used on your blade?

Comment: in trial model having cname,zipcode,lat & lng i want to fetch on view page this all. but as per my code in view $data not defined error message occure

Answer (score 0):

Change in controller

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{

    $data = Trial::where('zipcode',$request->zipcode)->select('lat','lng')->first();
    $lat = $data->lat;
    $lng = $data->lng;
    $distance = 5 ;// Diatanse in kms
    $query = Trial::getByDistance($lat, $lng, $distance);

    $ids = [];
    //Extract the id's
    if(!empty($query)) {
        foreach($query as $q)
        {
            array_push($ids, $q->id);
        }
    }

    // Now write final query 
    if(!empty($ids)){
        $results = DB::table('trial')->whereIn( 'id', $ids)->get();
    }

    return view('search.searchhome',['data' => $results]);
}
```

Change in blade

```
<p>
@foreach($data as $dat)
    {{$dat->zipcode}}
@endforeach                           
</p>
```

Comment: Update code in controller `$data = Trial::where('zipcode',$request->zipcode)->first();`

Comment: print `$data` in controller before pass on view. What you get ?

Comment: Sir actually return view('search.searchhome',['results'=>$results]);

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code.

```
if(!empty($ids)){
    $results = DB::table('trial')->whereIn( 'id', $ids)->get();
 }
```

Removed the `->where()`, the `where` clause had no condition. 
Added the `get()`, otherwise the query wont return any results.

```
return view('search.searchhome',compact('results'));
```

changed `data` to `results` as that contains your data.

```
dd($data);
```

remove the `dd()`, this does nothing as the function returns before it.

(I would also suggest to look into collections, instead of looping over the first result set)